# why is the click function not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, click, toggle

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g64s44ek/)

the '.item' click function that shows the '.pull_down_content' doesn't always work why is this? 
i've found that if you click the first 'tile' this will work fine and whilst that is open click the next tile still works fine but if you then go back to the original tile the click function stops working and only the hover works?

why is this?

here is part of my code..

```
    $(this).children('.item').on('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation();
     if ($('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
    if (!$(this).data('clicked')) {
        var Height = e.type==='mouseenter' ? '60px' : e.type==='click' ? '300px' : '0px';
        $(this).siblings('.pull_down_content').stop().animate({'height': Height}, 300); 

         $(this).siblings('.pull_down_content').children('.inner').css({'display': 'block'}, 300); 

        if (e.type==='click') $(this).data('clicked', true);
    }else{
        if (e.type==='click') {
            $(this).data('clicked', false);
            $(this).siblings('.pull_down_content').stop().animate({'height': '0px'}, 300);
   $(this).siblings('.pull_down_content').children('.inner').css({'display': 'none'}, 300);          

        }
    } }
                 });
```

Comment: Just glanced at the code but it looks like you are adding additional click events on the children every time you click on `'.timelineTile'`. You should move the above code outside of the `'.timelineTile'` click event. At the very least remove the existing events before re-adding them.

Comment: ahh can't believe it was that simple thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are adding additional click events on the children every time you click on '.timelineTile'. You should move the above code outside of the '.timelineTile' click event. At the very least remove the existing events before re-adding them.

Comment: the only thing i've found is sometimes after going from tile to tile the 'item' needs a click to get the hover and click function to work :S strange... http://jsfiddle.net/f45bhunL/

Comment: @Ziggy31 Did you get this figured out?  If not, let me know and I will check out your fiddle.

Comment: hey - nope still on with it - this is where i'm up to - http://jsfiddle.net/wks8s381/

Comment: for some reason after so many times of clicking - the hover/click doesn't work until you have clicked again.. its like the click back (height - 0) hasn't happened on the previous tile..

Comment: It looks like the problem occurs when you leave an "inner" area open then click on another tile.  When you go back to previous, you have to click twice.  I'm guessing the "state" of the "clicked" class is not in sync.

Comment: Not sure but try replacing `$('.timelineTile').not(this).removeClass('clicked').find('.pull_down_content').height(0);`   with this `$('.timelineTile').not(this).removeClass('clicked').find('.pull_down_content').height(0).end().find('.item').data('clicked',false);` .  Not 100% sure that's it but give it a shot.

Comment: you can add that as an answer on here if you like - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384341/why-does-the-hover-and-click-not-always-work